# 16.04 Desktop Sharing not enabling

Tags: 16.04, sharing

I have freshly installed 16.04 and checked all the appropriate boxes in Desktop Sharing, including Always under Show Notification Area Icon.

The Notification's drop down "Desktop Sharing is Enabled" is grayed out.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Desktop Sharing Preference Box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply run vino-server yourself.  First, kill the old server.

```
sudo killall vino-server
```

Then launch the server yourself.  You may wish to set the display, particularly if you're doing this over SSH.

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0
```

Once you have it working, wrap it in `nohup...&` and it will keep working until your next reboot:

```
nohup /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0 &
```